# clang performance drop when using uniform_real_distribution

Tags: c++, performance, gcc, distribution, clang++

The following code results in very different times for g++ and clang++ when using `uniform_real_distribution`.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>

#include <chrono>
#include <random>


std::mt19937::result_type seed = 0;
std::mt19937 gen(seed);
// std::uniform_int_distribution<size_t> distr(0, 1);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distr(0.0,1.0);

int main()
{
    auto t_start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    for (auto i = 1; i <= 1000000; ++i)
    {
        distr(gen);
    }
    auto t_end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
    std::cout << "elapsed time: " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::nanoseconds>(t_end - t_start).count()  << " ns\n" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with the following commands:

```sh
clang++ -std=c++17 -O3 -flto -march=native -mllvm -inline-threshold=10000000 rng.cpp -o rng
g++ -std=c++17 -O3 -march=native rng.cpp -o rng
```

this results in the following times:

```
clang:  272929774 ns

gcc:    12054635 ns
```

when using the commented distribution instead, the times are:

```
clang:  48155862 ns

gcc:    50226810 ns
```

I have found a quite old question here which handles the same problem however none of the proposed solutions worked in my case.

[Clang performance drop for specific C++ random number generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23240586/clang-performance-drop-for-specific-c-random-number-generation)

Does someone has an idea what is going on here?

Comment: `-O3` is dangerous especially when floating point is used! If you are playing with compilation flags [watch this](https://youtu.be/w5Z4JlMJ1VQ).

Comment: try with `distr(1.0, 2.0);`

Comment: `-O2` lead to the same picture. Unfortunately also `distr(1.0, 2.0);` does not help.

Comment: When performing these microbenchmarks, _always_ verify that your code isn't just optimized away!

Comment: Yes, as mentioned below, I actually would be glad if the code would be optimized away, when it is possible, so the question here should be, why clang cannot do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/DM59Cx)

On gcc compiler trashed `distr(gen);`!!!

```
.L27:
        dec     esi
        je      .L25
```

This is for loop which does nothing!

On clang compiler was not smart enough:

```
.LBB0_1:                                # =>This Inner Loop Header: Depth=1
        mov     edi, offset gen
        call    double std::generate_canonical<double, 53ul, std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 32ul, 624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615ul, 11ul, 4294967295ul, 7ul, 2636928640ul, 15ul, 4022730752ul, 18ul, 1812433253ul> >(std::mersenne_twister_engine<unsigned long, 32ul, 624ul, 397ul, 31ul, 2567483615ul, 11ul, 4294967295ul, 7ul, 2636928640ul, 15ul, 4022730752ul, 18ul, 1812433253ul>&)
        dec     ebx
        jne     .LBB0_1
```

And `generate_canonical` was actually called.

Basically you must use result of `distr(gen);` to do something with it what will have impact on code outcome, otherwise compiler can remove that code.

---

The [simplest way to fix i](https://godbolt.org/z/U0YYqK)t is to accumulate results of `distr(gen);` and print it.

Now when you look on assembly, you can see that `clang` is calling function `std::generate_canonical<double, 53ul, std::mersenne_twister_engine< .... >>` and `gcc` just placed that respective code inline.

Most probably this difference is caused by different organization of standard library. Clang used version built in into standard library and in gcc template from header file was used to generate code in just created assembly. When compiler reaches external code from library it can't tell what exactly it does, so it is unable to optimize away that code (since some side effects can be hidden in library).

Comment: Hello, could you think of a good way do so. However, in the "real" code where the problem occurred first, I definitely use this value so probably this is not the only reason here...

Comment: By the way, it would be fantastic if I could find the point why clang is **not** able to optimize it away. I am very interested in this optimization.

Comment: >> Most probably this difference is caused by different organization of standard library.
Yes, that is the point. Probably it is even a bug as it really turns down performance at this point. When performing simulations you essentially use random numbers all the time so my actual simulation became became twice as slow when using clang... Thanks for the advises and explanations.

Comment: Did you do measurements AFTER fix? I doubt difference is so big when `distr(gen);` wasn't discarded by gcc.

Comment: Yes, I have performed the measurements with your proposed version and the results are:

clang:

acc: 1.50021e+06 elapsed time: 328040263 ns

gcc:

acc: 1.50021e+06 elapsed time: 64385650 ns

Comment: So clang is still about 5 times slower.